# Why does my program crash with a stack overflow?

Tags: c, memcpy, sudoku

My program works fine when i use a 81 elements array but when i deal with a 256 blocks array it crashes and i dont know why it does that. I present to you the all source code and in the input text that you can use in a .txt file with a last carriage return.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int grille[256];
int domaine[256][17];     /* indique les valeurs possib pour case donnee */
int domaine_taille[256];     /* nombre de valeurs possibles une case donnee */
int compteur_noeuds;
void restreindre_domaines(int);
int backtrack(int imite_limite_par_ton_nez);

#define PERR(bSuccess, api) \
  {if (!(bSuccess)) perr(__FILE__, __LINE__,api, GetLastError());}
#define INCONNU -1

void lire_grille()
  {
  int k = 0;

  while (k < 256) { 
    char c = getchar();
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9' )  //0 a 9
      grille[k++] = c-48;
    if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')    // a a f
      grille[k++] = c-87;
    if (c == '.' || c == ' ' || c== '+') // espace  +  ou   .
      grille[k++] = INCONNU;
    if (c == EOF)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "Lecture de la grille : mauvais format\n");
      exit(1);
  }  }}

void afficher_grille()   /* afficher la grille courante sur stdout */
  {
  int c, l;

  for (l = 0; l < 16; l++) {
    for (c = 0; c < 16; c++) {
      int k = l*16+c;
      if (grille[k] == INCONNU) printf(".");
      if (grille[k] >= 0 && grille[k] <= 9 )  //0 a 9
        printf("%c", grille[k]+48);
      if(grille[k] >= 10 && grille[k] <= 15)    // a a f
        printf("%c", grille[k]+87);  
      }
    printf("\n");
    }
  printf("\n");
  }



void init_domaines()  /* en fonction grille,initialiser domaines */
  {
  int i, v;

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
    domaine_taille[i] = 16;
    for (v = 0; v <= 16; v++)
      domaine[i][v] = 1;
    }
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) /* restreindre domaines cases remplies */
    if (grille[i] != INCONNU)   restreindre_domaines(i);
  }



/*oter valeurs des domaines incompatibles avec valeur case i */
void restreindre_domaines(int i)
  {
  int l = i / 16;    //ligne
  int c = i % 16;   //colonne
  int lb = l / 4;   //
  int cb = c / 4;   //
  int l2, c2, lr2, cr2, i2;

  /* contraintes de la colonne contenant la case i */
  for (l2 = 0; l2 < 16; l2++) {
    i2 = l2*16+c;
    if (domaine[i2][grille[i]]!=0) {
      domaine[i2][grille[i]] = 0;
      domaine_taille[i2]--;
      }
    }

  /* contraintes de la ligne contenant la case i */
  for (c2 = 0; c2 < 16; c2++) {
    i2 = l*16+c2;
    if (domaine[i2][grille[i]]) {
      domaine[i2][grille[i]] = 0;
      domaine_taille[i2]--;
      }
    }

  /* verifier la region contenant la case i */
  for (lr2 = 0; lr2 < 4; lr2++)
    for (cr2 = 0; cr2 < 4; cr2++) {
      i2 = (lb*4+lr2)*16+(cb*4+cr2);
      if (domaine[i2][grille[i]]) {
        domaine[i2][grille[i]] = 0;
        domaine_taille[i2]--;
  }}}

int main()
  {
  lire_grille();
  afficher_grille();
  init_domaines();
  backtrack(0);
  printf("%d noeuds cherches\n", compteur_noeuds);

  printf(" \n");
  _getch();
  return 0;
  }

int backtrack(int uz)
  {
  if (uz==-99) return(uz);
  int i, i_min = -1,aa=0;
  int taille_min = 17;
  int domaine2[256][17];
  int domaine_taille2[256];
  static int toc,Toc;
  int iz,zzz=0;
  toc++;
  static int xu;
  xu=true;

  int lnum[16];

  lnum[0]=0;
  lnum[1]=15;
  lnum[2]=14;
  lnum[3]=13;
  lnum[4]=12;
  lnum[5]=11;
  lnum[6]=4;
  lnum[7]=3;
  lnum[8]=2;
  lnum[9]=1;
  lnum[10]=5;
  lnum[11]=10;
  lnum[12]=9;
  lnum[13]=8;
  lnum[14]=7;
  lnum[15]=6;

  int tst=0;
  for (iz = 0; iz < 256; iz++)
    {
    if (grille[iz] != INCONNU)tst++;
    }
  if(tst==256) 
    {   /*fin:*/
    // printf("\n%d  2  valeur tst\n", tst);
    afficher_grille();
    xu=0;
    return xu;
    }

  /* chercher la case avec le domaine le plus petit */
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
    if (grille[i] == INCONNU && domaine_taille[i] < taille_min)
      {
      i_min = i;
      taille_min = domaine_taille[i];
      //printf("i %d *do_tail[i] %d *tail_min %d \n",i,domaine_taille[i],taille_min);
      }

    if( toc >10000)
      {
      toc=0;
      afficher_grille();
      printf("\n%d noeuds cherches\n", compteur_noeuds);
      printf(" toc %d et Toc %d  \n",toc,Toc);
      Toc++;
      printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
      }
    }

  compteur_noeuds++;

  //    for (grille[i_min] = lnum[aa]; grille[i_min] <= lnum[aa+15]; grille[i_min]++,aa++)
  for (grille[i_min] = 0; grille[i_min] <= 15; grille[i_min]++,aa++)
    {
    if (domaine[i_min][grille[i_min]] == 0)
      continue;
      /* on sauvegarde l'etat courant de domaine
    et domaine_taille pour les retablir apres l'appel recursif */
    memcpy (domaine2, domaine, sizeof(domaine));
    memcpy (domaine_taille2, domaine_taille, sizeof(domaine_taille));
    restreindre_domaines(i_min);
    backtrack(uz);
    if (xu==0)return xu;
    memcpy (domaine, domaine2, sizeof(domaine));
    memcpy (domaine_taille, domaine_taille2, sizeof(domaine_taille));
    }
  grille[i_min] = INCONNU;
  return 0;
  }
```

VadeMecum: prog.exe < inp.txt

here is a inp.txt text with a good format  (16x16 1-F number and . for case to search)

```
.ae692...0..5.8d
5....4.12.37.bc6
..f.....5......4
.b.8e5f..9.d..01
.42b.17.3.......
.3.52....bf0...c
.......a.1..042b
....4.cb8...1..a
....f.4eb...3..8
.......5.3..acef
.7.2d....51f...9
.e3c.ab.0.......
.0.a58e..7.1..63
..1.....d......2
4....d.26.59.eb0
.6b7c9...4..d.15
```

So if you can help me .

Comment: Recommend reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Would also recommend trying to debug. Even worse you have some OS-specific includes in your program. If you want people to help you should definitely post a Minimal code that reproduces your errors. And variable names should be in english, not french ;)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `backtrack` requires approximately 20KB of stack *per recursive call*.  It's not obvious to me how deep the recursion goes, but if you're on Windows (as your code suggests) you only get 2MB of stack, and that's only enough for a recursion depth of 100 or so.  Consider using `unsigned short`, or maybe even `unsigned char` if all the necessary values will fit, for all the arrays.  If that isn't good enough you are going to have to get rid of the recursion and/or switch to heap allocated scratch arrays.

Comment: Which `81` which `256` ?

Comment: Simply don't use recursion and all your problems will go away. There exists very few valid uses of recursion and this is not one of them.

Comment: BTW: all those `memcpy`s in `backtrack` look suspicious to me, you probably shouldn't need them by reviewing your algorithm. BTW what is your program supposed to do ?

Comment: @Lundin I don't think that's useful advice for someone at the OP's level of understanding. Transforming a recursive algorithm into an iterative algorithm is often quite complicated, and they may not have gotten to those lessons yet.

Comment: Since the header file: `conio.h` is not portable, strongly suggest not using the functions it exposes.

Comment: for readability/understandability of the code, 1) indent consistently, suggest (for several reasons) 4 spaces per indent level. Indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'. 2) declare only one variable per statement,  only one statement per line 3) use meaningful variable names.  You may have to type a bit more characters, but it is well worth it.

Comment: The posted code is missing the header file: `stdbool.h` so `true` and `false` are not defined

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  then fix those warnings.

Comment: For readability by us humans, a bit of spacing, such as separating code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, etc) by a blank line and a horizontal space between parameters, etc would go al long ways

Comment: the code contains many `magic` numbers. `magic` numbers make the code more difficult to understand and are a major headache when debugging and/or maintaining the code.  Suggest using #defines or an enum to give those numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: the function: `lire_grille()` fails to handle capital letters and the local variable 'c' is defined as 'char', however getchar() returns an 'int' and EOF is an int.  So this line: `char c = getchar();`  should be: `int c = getchar();`  No other references to 'c' need to be changed

Comment: @ Michael Walz : 81 is the size of the array of sudoku game(9x9) so this works and 256 is the size of non working fine version (16x16 elements in array). Thanks, but in fine i don't understand why the 81 lements works and why the big not. The stack perhaps, i will try to size the stack up. Thanks for your advises.

Comment: such lines as: `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9' )` can be greatly simplified and much clear by adding: `#include <ctype.h>`  then replace the line with: `if( isdigit(c) )`.  similar simplifications/clarifications can be applied to the other if' statements in the `lire_grille()` function,  You might also want to use the `tolower()` function on all the input characters to reduce the amount of testing needed, such as tests for capital characters, etc.

Comment: @ user3629249: i am readind yours comments, i am happy that someone gives to me advises. So i have understand for magic numbers i will care about that. About stdbool.h i dont like use boolean variables but for my next question i will be care that this file will be in my code. Thanks for your experience.

Comment: you mention sudoku, which uses a 9x9 grid, no letters, no other values from the user,  So please explain why the letters a...f, ., space, + are expected inputs from the user.

Comment: @user3629249 When `char` is signed and `c < 0`, `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` is well defined.  `isdigit(c)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: the posted code uses the bool value `true`, so it is using boolean.  So the header `stdbool.h` needs to be included.

Comment: [@user3629249](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249) [Variations of grid sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku#Variations_of_grid_sizes) support 16x16 grids.

Comment: @chux,  isdigit(c) returns true when 'c' is in the range 0x30 through 0x39 and false for all other values of 'c', irregardless if 'c' is an 'int', as it should be for `getchar()`, or 'unsigned int'

Comment: @user3629249 Concerning `isdigit()`, the C spec says it is defined for all `unsigned char` values and `EOF`, not that range of `char`, which is `c`.  Agree `c` should be an `int`.  `unsigned int` has its shortcoming too.   Further, the spec does not specify the range 0x30 through 0x39, but `0` to `9` for portability reasons.

Comment: the stack size problem could be eliminated in the `backtrack()` function by using `malloc(`) to allocate the needed buffers and passing those buffers to `free()` when done with them.

Comment: @user3629249: No the reservation on stack space is not effcicient because the release goes after the last call in recursion. This system take the same space as the automatic reservation . (like in the program). I have the same problem.

Comment: my man page for isdigit() says the syntax is: `int isdigit(int c);`  I.E. a signed integer for a parameter.  my man page for getchar() says the syntax is: `int getchar(void);`  so it returns a signed integer, so the `isdigit()` function is very appropriate for the posted code to use.

Comment: @user3629249 except that OP used `char c`.  Had OP used `int c`, then `isdigit(c)` would be more readable as you commented.  But since OP user `char c`, `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` is well defined whereas your suggested visual improvement of `isdigit(c)` is not, -  as originally [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438687/why-does-my-program-crash-with-a-stack-overflow/33441613#comment54670206_33438687).

Comment: @chux, the getchar() function returns a int, the EOF value is an int.  The comparison of equal of a char to 0xffffffff (=EOF) will always fail.  Rather than try to justify an error in the code, simply fix it.

Comment: @user3629249,@chux,@all, if i want to push up the stack size just for my program ? can i do that ? and if yes how can i do that ? In the code a special constant or in the compil parameters or in linker parameters ? If you known tell me how i can do that because if i try the code with the **char** type (so 1  byte) the program has always the same comportement (it crashes with stack fault ...)

Comment: 1) stack size control is not a part of C, but of your compiler.  Review compiler options. 2) Clarify "try the code with the `char` type".  What variables are you changing to `char`?

Comment: @user3629249 "comparison of equal of a char to 0xffffffff (=EOF) will always fail"  is simply wrong when `char` has a range including negative values. What is the value of `CHAR_MIN` on your machine? On machines where `char` includes a negative range , quite common, `char c = CHAR_MIN; printf("%d", c);` will nicely print some negative number.  OP's code was not necessarily in error, but with `char c` and `c` having a negative value that is not `EOF`, `isdigit(c)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: By default, in C,  `char` is defined as 'unsigned'  so when comparing a char 0xff to EOF 0xffffffff  the char will be extended to 0x000000ff.  Then the two will not match.

Comment: @user3629249,@chux;  on my computer with limits header the C says that SCHAR_MAX  is 128 (or 255 with -j unsigned option) and INT_MAX is  2147483647, but this difference is not significative for my memory problem. I looking for the stack options on mvc and gcc bridges options tout increase my link-memory stack.

Comment: @user3629249 "By default, in C, `char `is defined as 'unsigned'" is inconsistent with the C spec.  Perhaps the spec is wrong and you are correct? `char` is same as `signed char` or `unsigned char`,  depending on the implementation.  What is the value of `CHAR_MIN` on your machine?  "If the value of an object of type `char` is treated as a signed integer when used in an expression, the value of `CHAR_MIN` shall be the same as that of `SCHAR_MIN` and the value of `CHAR_MAX` shall be the same as that of `SCHAR_MAX`. ..." C11 §5.2.4.2.1 2

Comment: @Chriistophe   Your comment "my computer with limits header the C says that `SCHAR_MAX` is 128".  If that is true, it is a very unusual machine.  Are you sure is wasn't 127?  BTW, what is the value of  `CHAR_MIN` on your machine?

Comment: @chux , i am wrong of course, i will say `SCHAR_MIN =CHAR_MIN= 127` and the mini on the other side for `-128 signed`, or `255 for non signeds` values. I am sorry.

Comment: @zenith, NathanOliver, Chris Beck, George Stocker
 
To change some things in a working programm you  all are champions, but to try made working an unstackable program you are not very cute. When i see your remarks , it s seems that all of you are  **Muppets**...  don t you know  ? You 're certainly very jalouse like are youngs ladies.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion too deep and too expensive in space. [@zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zwol)

I had the same stack over-flow.  Yet by changing `int` arrays to `char`, it was not too deep.  Recurse depth of 251 resulted in

```
cae69237104b5f8d
590da4812f37ebc6
72f1bcd0568e9a34
3b48e5f6a9cd7201
642b017d3c9a85fe
13a52e984bf06d7c
8c9e3f5a71d6042b
df7046cb8e25139a
0159f74eb2ac36d8
bd6410259378acef
a782d36ce51fb049
fe3c8ab90d642157
20da58efc7b14963
951f6b04d8e3c7a2
48c37d126a59feb0
e6b7c9a3f402d815

17310 noeuds cherches
```

Should this reduction prove to be insufficient, allocate memory for the arrays or alter the algorithm.

---

The code has various other short-comings, covered in comments, that obfuscate the central issue.  Fixing those do not solve the issue, but do make it easier for others (and likely OP) to diagnose.

Comment: @zwol: I thank you, I try with the other integral type.